# How to play the remote audio file using MediaElement in xaml

Tags: c#, xaml, windows-phone-8, mediaelement

The audio is playing well when giving the local audio file as the source for the `MediaElement`.

```
<MediaElement Grid.Row="1" Stretch="Uniform" Name="Player" Margin="0,93,0,0" Source="Assets/test.mp3"  />
```

But it is not working when try to play the remote audio file.

In the `MainPage.xaml.cs`

```
Player.Source = new Uri("http://fileraja.com/tamil/A/Alaipayuthey/Pachchai_Nirame-VmusiQ.Com.mp3", UriKind.RelativeOrAbsolute);
```

Please give me a solution. How to set the source for the `MediaElement` for a remote audio?

Answer (score 0):

I Used to add MediaElement to for ex. **MainPage.xaml** as:

```
<MediaElement Name="MediaContent" AutoPlay="True"/>
```

and in **MainPage.cs** *Constructor* or *OnNavigateTo* i Use:

```
 MediaContent.Source = new Uri("Ur Uri String Here", UriKind.Absolute);
```

if you don't want to auto play it *in page loading* just set *AutoPlay* to *False*, and play it on button click -for ex.- or any other event like that:

```
 MediaContent.Play();
```

if it doesn't work try to use:
**MediaFailed**,  **MediaOpened**, **MediaEnded** ,**CurrentStateChanged** .. events to keep track on why it doesn't work.